# response.out.write in python, google app engine not displaying on local host

Tags: python, google-app-engine, localhost, yaml

my yaml file:

```
application: testprogram
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

my python file:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.reponse.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write("Hurray for cake!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],debug=True)
```

from the sever:

```
$ dev_appserver.py testprogram
WARNING  2016-09-01 05:42:36,253 application_configuration.py:165] The "python" runtime specified in "testprogram/app.yaml" is not supported - the "python27" runtime will be used instead. A description of the differences between the two can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27
INFO     2016-09-01 05:42:36,265 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-09-01 05:42:36,400 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2016-09-01 05:42:36,635 simple_search_stub.py:1146] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.testprogram.rickus/search_indexes
INFO     2016-09-01 05:42:36,639 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:40100
INFO     2016-09-01 05:42:36,642 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-09-01 05:42:36,643 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2016-09-01 05:42:51,325 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

sever is up. Local host is up. But nothing is being written out. I am doing udacitys course so I have just began. What could the hang up be. Been checking the docs and still lost.

Comment: what do you see in the server logs?

Comment: editing to include now

Comment: I tired that and it didn't work. I am following the instructions from oreilly. Here is the website with instructions:

http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/web-services/excerpts/9780596800697/run-google-app-linux.html#starting_the_application_server-id003

Comment: Your request seems to have been handled ok - code 200. A bit odd, as you have a typo: `self.reponse.headers` instead of `self.response.headers` (but maybe you fixed that already). On your browser check the page source, maybe it's just not displayed properly.

Comment: side notes: with webapp2 you can do directly `self.response.write` instead of `self.response.out.write` (but both should work); and the other comment that was deleted in the meantime was a good one - you want `python27` instead of `python`, see 1st warning in the server log.

Comment: I'd also try to stop and restart of the server - sometimes it doesn't pick up changes properly.

Comment: You're supposed to request the `webapp2` library, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#requesting_a_library (but on my devserver it worked without it as well, so I'm not sure if this is it). To request a library you **need** the `python27` runtime. And changing the runtime will require a server restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in `app.yaml` file in the handlers section:

Yours:

```
application: testprogram
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

but you should have:

```
application: testprogram
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `.yaml` file, point the routing handler to main.app (not main.py).

You also have have typo in your python file. response is missing the first 's':

```
self.reponse.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
```

should be

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
```